# How can I force a plot to show me the bars in descending order?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I will show you my plot at this specific moment. As you can see the bar plots are not sorted according to the quantitative variable.

[image]

My original code is here

```
p1v <- ggplot(data = df_plot2, aes(x = reorder(gen, RQ_gapdh), y = RQ_gapdh, ymin = after_scale(1), fill = Color)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=.5)+ scale_fill_manual(values = c("indianred1", "olivedrab3" )) +
  labs(x = "Genes", y = 2^-ddCt~ "value",
       title = "Gene expression",
       subtitles = "1 year post-intervention")+
  guides(fill = F) +
  coord_flip()+
  facet_wrap(~grup_int, labeller = labeller(grup_int = c("1" = "Olive oil", "2" = "Nuts", "3" = "Low-fat diet")))
```

The modifications I have tried are meant to something like this (but are not working):

```
ggplot(data = df_plot2, aes(x = reorder(gen, RQ_gapdh), y = sort(RQ_gapdh, decreasing = T)

ggplot(data = df_plot2, aes(x = reorder(gen, RQ_gapdh), y = desc(RQ_gapdh)
```

The sample of data to reproducible example

```
df_plot2 <- structure(list(id = c(140102095, 140102087, 50109026, 120715030, 
140101097, 50118001, 110104029, 50202099, 70713002, 70802013, 
50203030, 120715030, 120715020, 70111023, 130108009, 60901027, 
120715035, 111202009, 130106037, 110113003, 130102014, 70111021, 
70204055, 70111024, 50109025, 50521002, 50203009, 60901026, 50203012, 
140101097, 140102090, 50203014, 130102014, 130108009, 111201007, 
60901023, 50203022, 50109027, 50203013, 50203026, 70204056, 120715021, 
130105045, 111201006, 50203030, 110104029, 50203026, 60901037, 
111202015, 140103027, 60901021, 70111023, 50203015, 120715020, 
130105044, 60901026, 140102089, 110113007, 50203031, 120715033, 
71801003, 140102088, 50527001, 120715033, 70713001, 110104030, 
120715030, 120715011, 130102013, 50203015, 70211014, 60901034, 
130102010, 60901037, 50203017, 50203031, 120715025, 50203032, 
50203026, 130102012), gen = c("cyp27a1", "abca1", "abca1", "ido", 
"msr1", "ptgs1", "icam1", "cxcl2", "il8ra", "gapdh", "dusp1", 
"nlrp3", "ldlr", "ppard", "nlrp3", "adrb2", "nfe2l2", "cxcl2", 
"cd86", "rxra", "cxcl2", "tnf", "lrp1", "cxcl8_il8_", "lag3", 
"il23a", "il23a", "rxra", "b2m", "slc2a3_glut3_", "b2m", "cdkn2a", 
"msr1", "ptgs1", "nlrp1", "cd36", "pcsk9", "s18", "ifng", "gapdh", 
"cd86", "s1pr3", "ccl3", "lag3", "ptgs1", "nr1h2", "lag3", "scarb1", 
"olr1", "cd40l", "il8rb", "il8ra", "lag3", "vcam1", "mttp", "chuk", 
"s1pr3", "chuk", "b2m", "olr1", "nr1h3", "tnf", "nlrp3", "ldlr", 
"nfkb1", "vcam1", "slc2a3_glut3_", "nlrp1", "cav1", "abcg1", 
"ifng", "cyp27a1", "ldlr", "rxrb", "nfe2l2", "nr1h2", "lag3", 
"nlrp1", "olr1", "rxra"), grup_int = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("1", 
"2", "3"), label = "GENERAL: Grupo de intervención", class = "factor"), 
    time = c("3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
    "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
    "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
    "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
    "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
    "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
    "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"), `-ddCt` = c(0.032, 
    0.243, 0.358, 0.003, 0.081, 0.255, 0.346, 0.028, 0.163, 0, 
    0.017, 0.138, 0.275, 0.33, 0.138, 0.053, 0.007, 0.183, 0.08, 
    0.153, 0.308, 0.165, 0.252, -0.137, 0.272, -0.364, -0.373, 
    -0.027, -0.612, 0.325, -0.612, 0.073, 0.081, 0.255, 0.251, 
    0.143, 0.033, -0.008, 0.012, 0, 0.08, 0.116, 0.324, 0.183, 
    -0.128, 0.265, 0.183, 0.306, -0.309, 0.194, 0.336, 0.387, 
    0.272, 0.341, 0.259, -0.09, 0.116, -0.138, -0.612, -0.493, 
    -0.042, 0.063, 0.138, 0.275, 0.28, 0.487, 0.181, 0.162, -0.079, 
    0, -0.396, 0.264, 0.369, 0.063, -0.025, 0.012, 0.183, 0.484, 
    -0.493, 0.277), RQ_gapdh = c(1.022, 1.183, 1.282, 1.002, 
    1.058, 1.193, 1.271, 1.019, 1.12, 1, 1.012, 1.1, 1.21, 1.257, 
    1.1, 1.037, 1.005, 1.135, 1.057, 1.112, 1.238, 1.121, 1.191, 
    0.909, 1.207, 0.777, 0.772, 0.982, 0.655, 1.253, 0.655, 1.052, 
    1.058, 1.193, 1.19, 1.104, 1.023, 0.995, 1.008, 1, 1.057, 
    1.084, 1.252, 1.135, 0.915, 1.201, 1.135, 1.237, 0.807, 1.144, 
    1.262, 1.308, 1.207, 1.267, 1.197, 0.94, 1.084, 0.909, 0.655, 
    0.711, 0.971, 1.045, 1.1, 1.21, 1.214, 1.401, 1.133, 1.119, 
    0.947, 1, 0.76, 1.201, 1.292, 1.045, 0.983, 1.008, 1.135, 
    1.399, 0.711, 1.212)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -80L))
```

Comment: you have three quantitative variables, which one do you want the bars sorted on?

Comment: (1) Cannot reproduce, there is no sample data. (2) I haven't found a question on SO asking about "order of bars/legends/axis-labels" that was not resolved by converting the categorical variables from `character`s to `factor`s and explicitly setting the order with `factor(., levels=...)`.

Comment: @GeorgeSavva there is just one, in the Y-axis, RQ_gapdh. This one is giving the stats identity in the bars. The three graph charts is because of the ~facet_wrap function

Comment: i understand that there is only one variable in the dataset, but this represents three different possible orderings of the genes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future questions you should provide a minimal reproducible example so people can work on your problem.

Here's what I'm guessing your data looks like:

```
so <- data.frame(gene = paste0("gene", 1:8),
             condition1 = c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3),
             condition2 = c(10,8,7,4,5,3,2,1),
             condition3 = c(9,8,7,6,2,3,4,5))
```

Using facet_wrap I've only been able to order by one of the conditions:

```
so %>% 
 pivot_longer(cols = 2:4, names_to = "condition", values_to = "values") %>% 
 ggplot(aes(x = reorder(gene, values), y = values))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=.5)+
  coord_flip()+
  facet_wrap(~condition, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Another option is to plot the conditions individually and put them together with ggarrange. With this option the order of your genes will change from one plot to the next:

```
p1 <- ggplot(so, aes(x = reorder(gene, condition1), y = condition1))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=.5)+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1.62)

p2 <- ggplot(so, aes(x = reorder(gene, condition2), y = condition2))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=.5)+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1.62)

p3 <- ggplot(so, aes(x = reorder(gene, condition3), y = condition3))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=.5)+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1.62)

library(ggpubr)
ggarrange(p1,p2,p3, nrow = 1)
```

The result will look like this:

[image]

Comment: Doing it individually, as you do, it is sorted each group in a decreasing order. I haven't realized it's not possible to do it for all 3 at once.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to assign the vector that contains your variables as factors and then set the factor levels. If I remember corectly, you can not change the order of displayed manually in ggplot2. It arranges the order automatically based on the level of factor assigned to a variable. Provie a reproducible example of data for better answer.

Comment: The variables gen and Color are factor class already. RQ_gapdh is numeric variable. Reprex provided!